# When validating data in Laravel 5.5, Update returns "unknown column in field list" error where Create does not

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-validation

Laravel 5.5 introduces a new streamlined request validation. The idea being that:

```
$validData = $request->validate($rules)
```

will return only those fields that are present in the `$rules`. This is beneficial so that one can then simply `User::create($validData)` or `User::update($validData)`.

However, I noticed that when I have additional data, which I do validate, but that doesn't exist in the model's (this case User) table, the `create` method inserts the record, but that the `update` method returns this error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'column_name' in 'field list'
```

I can of course write the relevant field lists out, or use other workaround, but I wonder why are the two methods are behaving differently?

e.g. passing

```
array:4 [▼
  "first_name" => "Pedro"
  "last_name" => "Taco"
  "email" => "taco@example.org"
  "operators" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "1"
  ]
]
```

to `User::create()` inserts the record. Passing the same to `User::update()` returns an error.
User has `$fillable = 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'`

Answer (score 0):

I believe they behave the same but in update method you have some extra fields that are not in table in database, so you should verify what exactly you send and what exactly you validate to make sure there are no additional fields in `$validData` when you are updating user.

If you think that's not the case, please show us exactly how the validation looks like for creating and updating user.

Comment: That's the thing, in both cases I'm sending additional fields, but why is create not throwing the error? Or better yet, update ignoring unknown data. Will add details to the question shortly.

Comment: Remember to show with which column is the problem too. Also are you sure the problem is for User and not for related models or some actions cause by events?

Comment: see details in the question above

Comment: You didn't include details. Still don't know which column causes the error, don't see validation rules and don't know if data passed to create and update are the same.

Comment: the array shown is the dump of the validated data (in both!). the `operators` field isn't on the model, and in `$fillable` but `create()` appears to ignore that.

Comment: As I said I don't think it's possible. You must not showing us something. If you pass the same array into create and update and have same fillable you shouldn't get any error. So it's possible you have some mutators or other stuff you are not showing us. Pass manually the same array (without using any validation) to create and update and confirm the error really exists

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update specific data use `where`

```
User::where('id',1)->update($validData);
```

If you want to update all rows try something like this

```
User::where('id','!=',-1)->update($validData);
```

OR

```
User::query()->update($validData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use validations, you can decouple the code even further using [Request validations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation).

---

Here you have a full example of applying Request validations and extracting just the necessary data to store (or update) objects:

#### 1. Generation the request:

```php
php artisan make:request CreateUserRequest
```

#### 2. Custom the validation rules:

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        // you specify here a previous condition before access to the method
        // can be Auth::check() for example
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // put here your validation rules like:
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:100',
        ];
    }
```

#### 3. Modify the method in your controller:

```php
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    // getting all the attributes
    $data = $request->only('first_name', 'last_name', 'other_attribute..');

    // creating the object
    $user = new User;
    // adding data
    $user->fill($data);
    // saving in database
    $user->save();

    return response()->json([
        "message" => "The user has been created.",
        "data" => $user,
    ], 201);
}
```

* Notice that the `$request` used as an argument is of type `CreateUserRequest`, so this indicates to Laravel wath rules to apply.

We have also **only** pull the data that we want to store (check the `$request->only` part), that seemed to be the root of your problem.